# What is the format of `CMakeCache.txt`

Tags: cmake

I am asking because I would like to enable syntax highlighting for `CMakeCache.txt` in my text editor (GNU Emacs).

Comment: See [My Customized cmake-mode.el includes support for CMakeCache.txt](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-January/012636.html). And [use a CMake GUI or the wizard mode (cmake -i) to edit cache entries](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#I_set_a_cmake_variable_in_my_environment.2C_but_it_didn.27t_change_anything._Why.3F).

Comment: Please convert your comment to an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Added an answer. I was given the comment, because I was not sure what your intentions of looking into or editing the CMakeCache.txt file are. So I just added general hints. Maybe you could add more on the background of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

There was a post [My Customized cmake-mode.el includes support for CMakeCache.txt](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-January/012636.html) back in 2007, so I'm not sure if it is still valid.

Generally speaking the `CMakeCache.txt` does not follow the normal CMake script syntax and maybe "topic to change".

So it's recommended to [Use a CMake GUI or the wizard mode (cmake -i) to edit cache entries](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#I_set_a_cmake_variable_in_my_environment.2C_but_it_didn.27t_change_anything._Why.3F).